# How to enter next activity after get Result from SERVER POST?

Tags: java, android, json, authentication, post

im new to android java coding, i need help with my login page, how should i enter to next activity when get result "Status" "Y", tried few solution its not working, what should i do?

```
btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            
            try {
                
                jsonObject.put("app_id", "123456");
                jsonObject.put("username",etUsername.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("password",etPassword.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("firebase_token", "123456");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            // put your json here
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("url")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();




            Response response = null;
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String myResponse = response.body().string();

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                TextViewResult.setText(myResponse);
                                if (myResponse == "Y") {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                                    // start the activity connect to the specified class
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });



                    }
                }
            });

        }


    }

    );
```

[image: Login Page]

Picture here, I get lot of result from my server, just need to detect "Status" "Y" and access the next activity, any suggestions?

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String myResponse = response.body().string();
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                 try {
                                     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                                     System.out.println(obj.getString("status"));
                                     System.out.println(obj.getString("status_desc"));
                                     System.out.println(obj.getString("token_id"));
                                 }
                                 catch (JSONException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                     TextViewResult.setText(JSONObject.getString("status"));
                                     if (JSONObject.getString("status") == "Y") {
                                         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                                         // start the activity connect to the specified class
                                         startActivity(intent);}
                                  }
                                 }
                        });



                    }
```

these r coding i added later, but still cant access to next activity, any suggestion?

Comment: You can parse your response in to a POJO class and from pojo class you will be easily able to access the status and all other keys which are you are getting in the login repsonse

Answer (score 0):

Your response.body() must be a JsonEntity. something like this

```
{
key1: "value",
key2: "value"
}
```

So basically you have to **pick** the key that is relevant to you using `value=response.body.optString("key1")` then use the value and check if you're getting the correct value and do the rest of the operations.
The response.body() gives you the whole Json.

Comment: but my login_token change every 30days, how's for it?

Comment: try {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myResponse);
System.out.println(obj.getString("status"));
System.out.println(obj.getString("status_desc"));
System.out.println(obj.getString("token_id"));
catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
TextViewResult.setText(JSONObject.getString("status"));
if (JSONObject.getString("status") == "Y") {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class); startActivity(intent);}}}

try this from someone, but still no working : error: non-static method getString(String) cannot be referenced from a static contex

Comment: it will be obj.optString("status") == "Y" || obj.getString("status") == "Y".. you are not using the JsobObject you created